# CoreData: Loading Integers out of a File

Tags: swift, core-data, integer, load, appdelegate

I got following code to load the data stored:

```
    func loadLevel(){
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Level")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do{
        let results:NSInteger = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        level = results
    }catch{
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

In the line where I am trying to store the data in the variabel results I get following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to specified type 'NSInteger' (aka 'Int')

I do know that I am not doing the error handling correct and as it should be. Thats the 'second step' on my list. Hopefully you can help me on my first problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `executeFetchRequest` returns an array of results, because fetches can and usually do return more than one result. These results can be of different types depending on how the fetch request was configured. So the return type is `[AnyObject]`.

You're attempting to assign the result of the fetch to a single `NSInteger`. You can't just assign an array of `AnyObject` like that. Your results will be zero or more instances of your `Level` instance, either instances of `NSManagedObject` or instances of a custom subclass you've configured for the entity.

What you should do is:

1. Change `results` to be of type `[AnyObject]`
2. Look through this array to find instances of `Level`
3. Get integer values from whichever attribute of `Level` contains the integer that you need.

Comment: It's the nature of the problem. You're doing something that by design can return multiple results. If you only need to store/read a single integer, `NSUserDefaults` would be much simpler and more appropriate.

Comment: Thank  you very much. Using `NSUserDefaults` to store data is a much easier way and it offers enough storage capacity.

Comment: It's only appropriate for a really small amount of data, though. Don't try to cram a lot of data into user defaults.